# How to map a complex object using Spliton and Types?

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to return a "Pessoa" List with your current "Endereco"
using Dapper.

```
public class Pessoa
{
        public string tipoPessoa { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string sobreNome { get; set; }
        public string emailAdress { get; set; }
        public Endereco endereco { get; set; }
}
public class Endereco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string complemento { get; set; }
}
```

My Method:

```
public IEnumerable<Pessoa> List()
    {
      var QUERY = @"SELECT P.Id, P.Nome, P.SobreNome, P.Email, P.IdTipoPessoa,
                           E.Bairro, E.Cep, E.Cidade, E.Complemento, E.Id, E.Rua as Logradouro
                      FROM Pessoa P
                INNER JOIN PessoaEndereco PE on P.Id = PE.IdPessoa
                INNER JOIN Endereco E on PE.IdEndereco = E.Id ";

      using (var conexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao))
      {
        return conexao.Query<Pessoa>(QUERY,
          splitOn: "IdTipoPessoa",
         //Mapping
          );
      }
    }
```

I know it's possible using `Types`, `Mapping` and `SplitOn`. How can I finish my method?

Comment: For Spliton to work correctly, rearrange your query to fetch `Id` for `Endereco`, post `IdTipoPessoa` it will take everything as `Endereco`, rest you can follow code posted underneath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be something like

```
using (var conexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao))
{
  return conexao.Query<Pessoa, Endereco, Pessoa>(QUERY,
    splitOn: "IdTipoPessoa",
    map: (p, e) => {
      p.endereco = e;
      return p;
    }
  );
}
```

More details can be found in this article I've written on the subject:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/multiple-mapping-d36c637d14fa